# Change css style with Jquery works on id's, not on classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this problem. I'm trying to change some css properties with jquery. One div has an ID, changing the property there works fine. The other div only has a class and the same command doesn't seem to apply there. Any idea?

Here's both approaches, the first one works, second doesn't:

```
 $('#editor').css('background-color', '#222');
 $('.divtag').css('color', '#222');
```

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: Nothing wrong here... maybe your classname is wrong, maybe you want to change the background but you changed color (instead of background-color...). Please fiddle

Comment: all works fine, just tested on stackoverflow - $(".question-hyperlink").css("color", "red")

Comment: like above users say, try it in JSFiddle first to see if it's just a syntax issue on your end: http://jsfiddle.net/r6m5m1f7/

Comment: When you say same command in `The other div only has a class and the same command doesn't seem to apply there` then I assume it should have been `$('.divtag').css('background-color', '#222');` And by the way `.divtag` is a very weak name for a class.

Comment: Now i read ".divtag" and think, maybe author mean just ".div" ? What mean "divtag"? div tag or div?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

In the CSS file, the .divtag had !important added to the color. For some reason that was blocking me from changing it with jquery.

Comment: `!important` takes priority over all CSS specificity rules, and it's also a rather difficult pseudo selector to include with jQuery `.css` changes.